# What is the correct syntax for replacing two characters at once in ColdFusion?

Tags: coldfusion, formatting, replace

I'm trying to replace two special characters using the replace function in ColdFusion:

```
<cfset MyQuery = "/Attribute One\/Attribute Two\/Attribute Three\">
<cfset MyString = Replace(MyQuery, "/", "<li>", "ALL")>
<ul>
<cfoutput>#MyString#</cfoutput>
</ul>
```

This works well, but I need to correctly close my li tags. I tried adding the following which did not work:

```
<cfset MyString = Replace(MyQuery, "/", "<li>", "ALL") AND Replace(MyQuery, "\", "</li>", "ALL")>
```

First question: Is this the right way to what I'm attempting? Or should I just store my html inside the database along with the attributes?

Second question: If my approach is correct, could someone please provide an example of the correct syntax?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nested replace? Just replace "/" first to avoid affecting "":

```
<cfset MyQuery = "/Attribute One\/Attribute Two\/Attribute Three\" />

<cfset MyString = Replace(MyQuery, "/", "<li>", "ALL") />
<cfset MyString = Replace(MyString, "\", "</li>", "ALL") />
<cfoutput>#MyString#</cfoutput>

<cfset MyString = Replace(Replace(MyQuery, "/", "<li>", "ALL"), "\", "</li>", "ALL") />
<cfoutput>#MyString#</cfoutput>
```

List manipulation can be another the way to do this:

```
<cfset MyQuery = "/Attribute One\/Attribute Two\/Attribute Three\">

<cfset MyString = "" />

<cfloop list="#MyQuery#" index="li" delimiters="\/">
    <cfset MyString &= "<li>#li#</li>" />
</cfloop>

<cfoutput>#MyString#</cfoutput>
```

Comment: That's brilliant, thank you. Is there a way to include the ul tags in this?

Comment: String concatenation with & used in second example. So this can be done as <cfset MyString = "<ul>" & MyString & "</ul>" />